# Identity Server -3 Clarification

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am new to identity server and I seem to get confused about the whole stuff. I like to build an application where the API will serve as a "User store" (like a generalised place for all users that can access different web applications that I created), meaning can send user details with their claims and based on this, redirect users to the web application(ASP.NET MVC app) they want to access.

I have seen majorly examples where the client (MVC/JS APP) reside in the same solution as identity server and this is kind of far from what I intend to do. Can anyone suggest an example that could help in this case?

Also having implemented different examples, I like to clarify these:
- Using the typical identity server 3 implementation, you need to include the certificate in the project
- Using the OWIN/ASP.NET packages, you do not need to include the certificate.

Please what is the difference. I am sorry if this a question that seems odd, but I need to understand this concept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer should be hosted on its own in most scenarios. I have a blog article that walks through such a setup: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-1

IdentityServer is a OWIN/Katana library and the token signing certificate must always be loaded into IdentityServer, as the private key is necessary to sign tokens.